# Изменение ссылки и переход на другую Activity по нажатию кнопки

Tags: android, android-button, videoview

Допустим  есть три кнопки и другое Activity c videoview,при нажатии на одну кнопку я должен перейти на эту страницу и ссылка на видеовью должна стать той,которая будет задана.При нажатии второй и третьей кнопки должно быть аналогично.Такое возможно.

Comment: Такое возможно.

Comment: Intent put extra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для передачи параметров используйте Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
String strName = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

В последствии во второй активности получайте данный параметр.

```
String newString;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
```